# Receiving ' not a servlet class ' error while deploying a maven war to websphere portal

Tags: java, maven, websphere, websphere-portal

I have converted a portlet project into maven and created its war file . When I am deploying the war file , it does not generate any error in the websphere portal console but in the SystemOut.log file generates the following error log -----

```
[8/29/17 18:01:45:380 IST] 00006095 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser endElement JSPG0235E: The JSP container failed to loa
d the TagExtraInfo class [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.XmlTransformTEI]  from META-INF/x-1_0-rt.tld
[8/29/17 18:01:45:381 IST] 00006095 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser endElement JSPG0235E: The JSP container failed to loa
d the TagExtraInfo class [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.XmlParseTEI]  from META-INF/x-1_0.tld
[8/29/17 18:01:45:381 IST] 00006095 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser endElement JSPG0235E: The JSP container failed to loa
d the TagExtraInfo class [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.XmlTransformTEI]  from META-INF/x-1_0.tld
[8/29/17 18:01:45:381 IST] 00006095 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser endElement JSPG0235E: The JSP container failed to loa
d the TagExtraInfo class [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.XmlParseTEI]  from META-INF/x.tld
[8/29/17 18:01:45:382 IST] 00006095 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser endElement JSPG0235E: The JSP container failed to loa
d the TagExtraInfo class [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.XmlTransformTEI]  from META-INF/x.tld
[8/29/17 18:01:45:418 IST] 00006095 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally CWSRV0266E: Error o
ccured while initializing servlets: {0}
                                 javax.servlet.UnavailableException: CWSRV0201E: Servlet [com.bluestar.servlet.InitializationServlet]: no
t a servlet class
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1501)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:1475)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1354)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:614)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:584)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:425)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:746)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1379)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2189)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:664)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:678)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:622)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1269)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor98.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:291)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1260)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:300)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1254)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1092)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1482)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1371)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1320)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor98.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:291)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1260)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:300)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1254)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1092)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor327.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:488)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:322)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:522)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)

[8/29/17 18:01:45:419 IST] 00006095 webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication CWSRV0250I: Web Module CMSMaterialRequestPortlet has been bound to default_host[*:10012,*:80,*:10014,*:10028,*:10029,*:443,*:10039,*:10042,*:10041].
[8/29/17 18:01:45:448 IST] 00006095 ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0221I: Application started: PA_CMSMaterialRequest
[8/29/17 18:01:45:448 IST] 00006095 CompositionUn A   CWWSR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=PA_CMSMaterialRequest in BLA WebSphere:blaname=PA_CMSMaterialRequest started.
[8/29/17 18:03:00:842 IST] 000000f4 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
[8/29/17 18:03:00:848 IST] 000000f4 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
```

When I am assigning this portlet to a page in websphere portal & am trying to display the portlet gui , then it gives message as ' Portlet not available '. The original war file is created using ant and it is deployed successfully . I tested by deploying this original war file in my portal server and it is working perfectly fine .

**Following are some of the lines of the exception that I got after changing the class loader -----
[9/8/17 1:57:53:969 IST] 0000019d AdminHelper   A   CWWMN1010I: An attempt is made to stop the PA_CMSMaterialRequest application. (User ID = defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin)
[9/8/17 1:57:53:970 IST] 0000019d CompositionUn A   CWWSR0192I: Stopping composition unit WebSphere:cuname=PA_CMSMaterialRequest in BLA WebSphere:blaname=PA_CMSMaterialRequest.
[9/8/17 1:57:53:975 IST] 0000019d ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0217I: Stopping application: PA_CMSMaterialRequest
[9/8/17 1:57:54:036 IST] 0000019d webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log CWSRV0292I: Servlet Message - [PA_CMSMaterialRequest#CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war]:.Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[9/8/17 1:57:54:722 IST] 0000019d ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0220I: Application stopped: PA_CMSMaterialRequest
[9/8/17 1:57:56:776 IST] 0000019d CompositionUn A   CWWSR0193I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=PA_CMSMaterialRequest in BLA WebSphere:blaname=PA_CMSMaterialRequest stopped.
[9/8/17 1:58:18:601 IST] 0000066b AdminHelper   A   CWWMN1008I: An attempt is made to start the PA_CMSMaterialRequest application. (User ID = defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin)
[9/8/17 1:58:18:664 IST] 0000066b CompositionUn A   CWWSR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=PA_CMSMaterialRequest in BLA WebSphere:blaname=PA_CMSMaterialRequest.
[9/8/17 1:58:18:690 IST] 0000066b ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0200I: Starting application: PA_CMSMaterialRequest
[9/8/17 1:58:18:690 IST] 0000066b ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0204I: Application: PA_CMSMaterialRequest  Application build level: Unknown
[9/8/17 1:58:21:625 IST] 0000066b webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup CWSRV0169I: Loading Web Module: CMSMaterialRequestPortlet.
[9/8/17 1:58:21:675 IST] 0000066b WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext CWSEN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key default_host/wps/PA_CMSMaterialRequest
[9/8/17 1:58:21:694 IST] 0000066b MBeanDescript I   CWWMN1216I: One or more methods in Portlet mbean is excluded from access check.
[9/8/17 1:58:21:703 IST] 0000066b MBeanDescript I   CWWMN1216I: One or more methods in PortletApplication mbean is excluded from access check.
[9/8/17 1:58:22:099 IST] 0000066b webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log CWSRV0292I: Servlet Message - [PA_CMSMaterialRequest#CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war]:.Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[9/8/17 1:58:22:100 IST] 0000066b ContextLoader I org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[9/8/17 1:58:22:245 IST] 0000066b XmlWebApplica I org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Sep 08 01:58:22 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
[9/8/17 1:58:22:467 IST] 0000066b XmlBeanDefini I org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
[9/8/17 1:58:22:645 IST] 0000066b ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
                                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:171)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:481)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1686)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:746)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2189)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:664)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:678)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:622)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1269)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:291)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1260)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:300)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1254)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1092)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:241)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:578)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:955)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3837)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)**

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: Hi Pradeep ..... I have posted my web.xml and portlet.xml ..... do let me know if you require any other info ?

Answer (score 1):

The "not a Servlet class" message almost always indicates a packaging problem, in which the application includes its own copy of the Servlet API in a PARENT_LAST class loader.  When the web app is started, the server's web container loads the Servlet class from the application.  The web container links to the version of Servlet packaged in the server's Java EE APIs, while the application class links to the version of Servlet packaged along with it.  Classes loaded by separate class loaders are considered incompatible by the JVM (regardless of their actual bytecode), so the resulting cast fails.

The solution is to either switch your web module's class loader to PARENT_FIRST or to remove the Servlet API (really, any Java EE APIs, unless you're explicitly using your own version of something) from your application.  Either solution should eliminate this issue.

Comment: Hi Jarid ...... As per your suggestion , I went to WebSphere enterprise applications & open my portlet application in websphere console .There was an option ' Class loading & update detection '. In that , by default it was selected as ' Classes loaded with local class loader first '. I selected ' Classes loaded with parent class loader first '. But when I tried to view the portlet , it gave the same message as ' Portlet is unavailable '

Comment: It gave the same set of errors as ----------------------------------------------[9/1/17 3:04:06:198 IST] 00000137 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
[9/1/17 3:04:06:208 IST] 00000137 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet

Comment: Also , I would like to tell you that the original war contains four folders ---- images , js , META-INF and web-INF . But when I convert this war to maven , my entire structure changes . The images and js folder are put under ' WEB-INF ' directory . Can this be a source of the problem ?

Comment: What is the actual exception thrown when you switch the class loading mode?  It's not clear whether it's the same exception or something new.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear regarding this . Actually the error generated at the time of deployment only . Once the file got deployed , I stopped the application, changed the class loader for that particular application and then started it again . After that when I checked the portlet page , it showed portlet is unavailable . The errors were the same errors which got generated earlier while trying to view the portlet i.e Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet

Comment: The "Uncaught..." message is just a wrapper for the actual error. Is it still the "not a Servlet class" thing?

Also, double-check that when you changed the class loading mode, you switched it for the web module and not just the application - they have separate class loaders.

Comment: Hi Jarid , As far as what I have checked , the error has not changed . While deploying the war file , it still generated not a servlet class error . From what I have seen in the WebSphere console , when an application is deployed , when we click on that ear file , then in the class loading option it itself gives option to load from local class loader or parent class loader . I selected parent class loader . I did'nt see any other option to select class loader for the web module as well . Can you tell me where to find it ?

Comment: I don't have a server in front of me, but I believe after you select the application EAR in the WebSphere console, there should be "Manage modules" somewhere on the page, and from there you can select your web module, which will have similar class loading settings.  Also, did you check whether you actually had the Servlet API in your app?  If so, just removing it would also solve the issue; it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Hi Jarid , Thank you for your response . My websphere portal server has screwed up . For checking purpose , I took access of another server . I just clicked on the deployed application in the websphere console and found there was a 'Manage Modules ' section . As for now , it contained the option ' Class loaded with local class loader first (parent class) option . I cannot modify the things in another server . Hence , I need to create a new server . I will test after that .  .

Comment: Also , you said to remove the servlet API . I have attached the web.xml for your reference . If you see the last two parts which contains ' InitializationServlet ' , this is the code related to that . The error is coming at this point . But if I remove it , how would the portlet run ?

Comment: The "servlet API" I'm referring to here would most likely be a jar in your WAR file's WEB-INF/lib directory, not an entry in an XML file.  Everything in WEB-INF/lib is placed on the class path of the WAR's class loader, and when you run with PARENT_LAST, everything there is loaded in preference to what is packaged with the server. My assumption based on your failure is that one of those jar files contains javax.servlet.Servlet inside it.

Comment: Hi Jarid , I have changed the class loader for ' Managed Modules ', ' Class loading & update detection ' and at the application level . After that , when I restarted the portlet , exception generated . I am attaching the exception . Please check . It says class not found exception .

Comment: Is that class in the application?  If so, is it in a location that's on the application's class path (WEB-INF/lib, or a lib directory within the EAR)?

Also, were you running with PARENT_LAST for some specific reason?  It could be that your application legitimately needs that type of class loading delegation (for example, if you're bringing your own version of some library), in which case the "remove the Servlet API from your web module" action is still necessary.

Comment: I checked for the Servlet API . In the maven dependencies , I found one dependency named as servlet-api.jar . This jar file contained javax.servlet.Servlet class . I removed this dependency but the issue is still persisting . When I deployed the portlet , by default it was selected as parent last . I never used to change the class loaders for this . The original ant war used to successfully run using the default class loaders . I am still searching for other servlet apis in which I cam find javax.servlet.Servlet but I don't think there are more than this .

Comment: Regarding the class not found error , I saw that earlier there was a jar file which was used in the ant war dependency . The name of this jar file is org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar . This jar file contains this class file but I did not include it in dependency as the maven war file compiled without it . Is it necessary to include it as a dependency ?

Comment: Given that the JVM is looking for the class, I'd assume the jar has to be included.

Comment: Hi Jarid , Thanks for your support till now . As per your suggestion , I changed the class loader to parent first in the ' class loading & update detection section ' and ' manage modules ' section . I have removed all the errors which were generating during change of class loader . I have even removed the javax.servlet classes . But even now the portlet gui is not visible .

Comment: It is still showing the following errors ----               [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.XmlTransformTEI]  from META-INF/x.tld
[9/11/17 12:30:39:238 IST] 000000f5 webapp      Error occured while initializing servlets: {0}
                                 javax.servlet.UnavailableException: CWSRV0201E: Servlet [com.bluestar.servlet.InitializationServlet]: not a servlet class
 at

Comment: I have found one more thing ...... there is a dependency named websphere_apis.jar ...... I saw that this jar also contains javax.servlet.Servlet class ...... but the problem is that without this jar the maven portlet war file is not compiling .

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar with Maven, but you need to find a way to make the jar available for compilation and not include it in the app.  The websphere_apis jar is provided so you can compile your apps against the necessary server classes, but it's not to be used as an application library (the idea is that the APIs in that jar are all provided by the server).

Comment: Hi Jarid , A per your suggestion , I allowed the jar to be available for compilation only and excluded it from WEB-INF/lib . The ' not a servlet class ' error is not coming now . Thanks !!! . But the main issue has not solved yet . The portlet gui is still not showing . In SystemOut.log , it is only showing ' [9/12/17 12:32:51:494 IST] 00000665 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet ' . Apart from this , no other errors are visible in SystemOut.log file . I can't make out what is the issue ?

Comment: Glad to hear that worked.  On the "Uncaught init exception", check to see if there's either an FFDC message from that part of the log or a nested exception saying what the "uncaught init exception" was caused by.

Comment: I'd also note that from a larger Stack Overflow perspective, the issue in the original question was answered, so it might make sense to address the next underlying issue in a separate question at this point, in the event that the new question is something that a user may also want to search (at the moment, I think we have a pretty relevant question/answer pair for the "not a servlet class" issue).

Comment: Hi Jarid , Unfortunately , it is not generating any other stack traces apart from that wrapper error . That is why I am not able to understand that what is the issue in the background ? As per your suggestion , I have raised a seperate question for that . If you can guide me in this , then you can post an answer there .

Comment: You can answer the question in the below link ----- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211333/receiving-uncaught-init-exception-thrown-by-servlet

Comment: Hi Jarid , I am facing an issue in java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent . The description for the problem is given in the following link ----  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523828/java-lang-exception-java-lang-verifyerror-jvmvrfy012-stack-shape-inconsistent . Can you please tell me what is the issue and how can we solve it ?