# Receiving Uncaught.init.exception thrown by servlet?

Tags: java, maven, ant, websphere, websphere-portal

I have converted an ant project and converted into maven. Now when I am deploying this war file on the websphere portal server, it is generating exception as follows -----

> [9/13/17 14:06:43:750 IST] 00000474 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet

Apart from this, it is not generating any other stack traces. I have used `RAD (Rational Application Developer)` to convert the project into maven. Can anybody help me with this issue ?

Following is the full stack trace which I got while deploying -----

```
[9/14/17 16:21:27:751 IST] 0000109d InstallSchedu I   ADMA5016I: Installation of PA_CMSMaterialRequest started.
[9/14/17 16:21:33:556 IST] 0000109d InstallSchedu I   ADMA5013I: Application PA_CMSMaterialRequest installed successfully.
[9/14/17 16:21:34:751 IST] 00000121 EditScheduler I   ADMA5075I: Editing of application PA_CMSMaterialRequest started.
[9/14/17 16:21:35:039 IST] 00000121 EditScheduler I   ADMA5076I: Application PA_CMSMaterialRequest edited successfully. The application or its web modules may require a restart when a save is performed.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:636 IST] 00000120 AppBinaryProc I   CWWMA7021I: Distribution of application PA_CMSMaterialRequest completed successfully.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:913 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:915 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:915 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war/WEB-INF/dealerMaterialRequest-portlet.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:915 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:915 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war/WEB-INF/dealerMaterialFollowUp-portlet.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:915 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/META-INF/ibm-application-runtime.props.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:918 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war/WEB-INF/mcoMaterialDispatch-portlet.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:918 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/META-INF/was.module.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:918 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/cus/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/cver/BASE/controlOpDefs.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:918 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/META-INF/was.webmodule.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:920 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:920 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war/WEB-INF/areaManagerMaterialRequest-portlet.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:920 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deltas/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/delta-1505386293273.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:920 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war/WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xmi.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:920 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war/WEB-INF/mcoMaterialRequest-portlet.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:923 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/META-INF/was.policy.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:923 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/META-INF/application.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:923 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/deployment.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:923 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war/WEB-INF/portlet.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:923 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/cus/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/cver/BASE/cu.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:925 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deltas/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/delta-1505386294989.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:925 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:925 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/blas/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/bver/BASE/bla.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:925 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war/WEB-INF/web.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:925 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/cus/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/cver/BASE/cu-ref.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:925 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal created document cells/VLap1084Cell/applications/PA_CMSMaterialRequest.ear/deployments/PA_CMSMaterialRequest/CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war/WEB-INF/log4j.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:37:925 IST] 00000120 FileRepositor A   CWWMR0016I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal modified document cells/VLap1084Cell/nodes/VLap1084Node/serverindex.xml.
[9/14/17 16:21:39:938 IST] 00000120 AdminHelper   A   CWWMN1008I: An attempt is made to start the PA_CMSMaterialRequest application. (User ID = defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/server:VLap1084Cell_VLap1084Node_WebSphere_Portal)
[9/14/17 16:21:39:980 IST] 00000120 CompositionUn A   CWWSR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=PA_CMSMaterialRequest in BLA WebSphere:blaname=PA_CMSMaterialRequest.
[9/14/17 16:21:40:000 IST] 00000120 ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0200I: Starting application: PA_CMSMaterialRequest
[9/14/17 16:21:40:000 IST] 00000120 ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0204I: Application: PA_CMSMaterialRequest  Application build level: Unknown
[9/14/17 16:21:42:064 IST] 00000120 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup CWSRV0169I: Loading Web Module: CMSMaterialRequestPortlet.
[9/14/17 16:21:42:099 IST] 00000120 WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext CWSEN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key default_host/wps/PA_CMSMaterialRequest
[9/14/17 16:21:42:114 IST] 00000120 MBeanDescript I   CWWMN1216I: One or more methods in Portlet mbean is excluded from access check.
[9/14/17 16:21:42:119 IST] 00000120 MBeanDescript I   CWWMN1216I: One or more methods in PortletApplication mbean is excluded from access check.
[9/14/17 16:21:42:419 IST] 00000120 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log CWSRV0292I: Servlet Message - [PA_CMSMaterialRequest#CMSMRMSP-0.0.1-SN.war]:.Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[9/14/17 16:21:42:419 IST] 00000120 ContextLoader I org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[9/14/17 16:21:42:449 IST] 00000120 XmlWebApplica I org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Sep 14 16:21:42 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
[9/14/17 16:21:42:479 IST] 00000120 XmlBeanDefini I org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
[9/14/17 16:21:42:637 IST] 00000120 DefaultListab I org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e7e2d6bf: defining beans [dataSource,searchBusinessServiceImpl,searchBusinessService,retrieveBusinessServiceImpl,retrieveBusinessService,insertUpdateBusinessServiceImpl,insertUpdateBusinessService,searchDAOImpl,searchDAO,retrieveDAOImpl,retrieveDAO,insertUpdateDAOImpl,insertUpdateDAO,viewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
[9/14/17 16:21:42:939 IST] 00000120 ContextLoader I org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 520 ms
[9/14/17 16:21:42:944 IST] 00000120 ClassPathXmlA I org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@7b36cd85: startup date [Thu Sep 14 16:21:42 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
[9/14/17 16:21:42:946 IST] 00000120 XmlBeanDefini I org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
[9/14/17 16:21:42:996 IST] 00000120 DefaultListab I org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@9f6318cc: defining beans [dataSource,searchBusinessServiceImpl,searchBusinessService,retrieveBusinessServiceImpl,retrieveBusinessService,insertUpdateBusinessServiceImpl,insertUpdateBusinessService,searchDAOImpl,searchDAO,retrieveDAOImpl,retrieveDAO,insertUpdateDAOImpl,insertUpdateDAO,viewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
[9/14/17 16:21:43:009 IST] 00000120 ServletWrappe I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init CWSRV0242I: [PA_CMSMaterialRequest] [/wps/PA_CMSMaterialRequest] [InitializationServlet]: Initialization successful.
[9/14/17 16:21:43:011 IST] 00000120 webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication CWSRV0250I: Web Module CMSMaterialRequestPortlet has been bound to default_host[*:10012,*:80,*:10014,*:10028,*:10029,*:443,*:10039,*:10042,*:10041].
[9/14/17 16:21:43:061 IST] 00000120 ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0221I: Application started: PA_CMSMaterialRequest
[9/14/17 16:21:43:061 IST] 00000120 CompositionUn A   CWWSR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=PA_CMSMaterialRequest in BLA WebSphere:blaname=PA_CMSMaterialRequest started.
[9/14/17 16:25:48:700 IST] 000001b6 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
[9/14/17 16:25:48:713 IST] 000001b6 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
```

I got the following exception from the ffdc logs ---

```
[9/18/17 13:57:41:567 IST] 00000106 ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
                             java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/expression/spel/SpelParserConfiguration.<init>(Lorg/springframework/expression/spel/SpelCompilerMode;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.<init>(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:629)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1686)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:746)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2189)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:664)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:678)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:622)
```

Comment: do you have an init method overridden in your servlet?  what is the full stack trace>

Comment: Please refer the full stack trace which I attached above ...... of these I only find the last two lines as error .

Comment: Have you checked SystemErr.log or your FFDC logs (although I don't see an obvious FFDC message in the portion of the log you included here)?  Sometimes that stuff gets written to the error stream and not the output stream.

Comment: Hi Jarid , I checked the SystemErr log file .No recent updates have been added in the error log file . The logs are getting generated in the SystemOut logs only .

Comment: Jarid , Could it because of a missing servlet dependency which is reqd for viewing the portlet gui ? I was thinking as some servlet jar should be present , not in the WEB-INF/lib folder , but atleast for compilation purpose which would help it to consider it as a servlet class .

Comment: You may apply fix pack to your WAS - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI70493 - maybe it will provide some more info on that error.

Comment: I would probably turn on webcontainer tracing, or if you want to provide a sample war we can examine it

Comment: I Got the above posted exception in the ffdc logs . Earlier it was generating a portlet exception error , but when I solved that , I started getting this exception . Please note that the relevant class file exists in the jar . Can anybody tell me what it is and how to resolve it ?

Comment: A NoSuchMethodError usually means that you have two different versions of some library available.  I don't think WebSphere bundles Spring for applications to pick up, so my guess is that you have two different jars in your application that have this same class in them.  Ideally you can figure this out by reviewing the contents of your app, but if you're not able to for whatever reason, you can always flip on verbose class loading to see where the classes are loading from.  StandardBeanExpressionResolver and SpelParserConfiguration would be the important ones.

Comment: Thank you Jarid ..... your suggestion worked ..... It contained same version jars .... I removed one of them .... the error has removed now ..... thanks ....

Comment: Right now receiving a new set of error -----  [9/18/17 21:25:33:652 IST] 000000e8 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service CWSRV0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause dealerMaterialFollowUp: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.portlet.PortletException: Error occured during request processing: org/springframework/web/context/request/NativeWebRequest.getNativeRequest(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;  In the net some solutions were given which I tried , but the error is not going . Is there a compatibility issue between two jars ?

Comment: That exception doesn't really have anything to go on - my guess is that the PortletException is wrapping some other exception, and the method name there is the message text of that underlying exception.  Hopefully there's a "caused by" in the exception stack or another useful FFDC.

Comment: Hi Jarid , your suggestion was absolutely right . There was a caused by error which again showed no such method error . I resolved it . After that numerous exceptions raised . I resolved all of them and finally I am able to view my portlet gui . Thank you for the inevitable support you provided me . Really appreciated .

Comment: Thanks to rest of the persons for their valuable suggestions .

Comment: Can anybody tell me about the following error -----    [9/24/17 20:23:23:685 IST] 00000168 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service CWSRV0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [AdhocReportingTool] in application [PA_AdhocReportingTool]. Exception created : [java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.wps.services.portletserviceregistry.home.PortletServiceHomeImpl incompatible with com.ibm.portal.portlet.service.PortletServiceHome

Comment: [9/25/17 10:03:40:013 IST] 0000011f ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sf' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;