# java.lang.Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent

Tags: java, maven, websphere, websphere-portal

I am deploying a maven war file on websphere portal version 8.5 . While deplying , I am getting the following error ----

```
[10/2/17 15:43:14:658 IST] 00000131 DispatcherPor E org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet processRequest Could not complete request
                                 javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=com/ibm/_jsp/_SearchCRO, method=_jspx_meth_c_forEach_0(Ljavax/servlet/jsp/tagext/JspTag;Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext;[I)Z, pc=76
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.core.impl.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:127)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doRender(DispatcherPortlet.java:1137)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.render(DispatcherPortlet.java:1092)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doRenderService(DispatcherPortlet.java:761)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:522)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.doDispatch(FrameworkPortlet.java:470)
        at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:222)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:128)
        at com.ibm.wps.engine.el.init.AttributeCopyFilter.doFilter(AttributeCopyFilter.java:158)
        at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
        at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.capabilities.filter.PortletCapabilityDependencyFilter.doFilter(PortletCapabilityDependencyFilter.java:279)
```

Can anybody tell me what is the issue and how to resolve it ?

Comment: did you resolve this, please ?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in regards to the error
I experienced the same error a while ago when I was trying to upgrade from IBM JRE 1.7.0 SR3 to 1.7.0 SR5. The research about this very error has been going ever since. So far I have found the following things:
1) in SR5, IBM introduced an improved bytecode verification, which obviously doesn't like bytecode that has been compiled for/from a different version.
2)  if the bytecode was complied for/from the same version and adjusted afterwards (with tools such as AspectJWeaver and similar), which is my very case, the IBM JVM doesn't like that as well.
So, in case you are not using any bytecode modifications, you might get lucky. Try compiling the affected classes with a newer version of the JDK.
If you are indeed using tools like AspectJWeaver, can't help you. I have opened a bug report in the Eclipse Foundation bug tracking system and I am waiting for a response.

Another recommendation was to try upgrading to later than sr6 now that it is out

Comment: I have java 1.8 installed . Is there any need to change the java version ?

Comment: So if you changed portal to use the 1.8 JRE instead of the 1.7, try and see if you are on the latest SR for 1.8